# How can view detect template rerendered changed?

Tags: ember.js

```
{{#view 'container'}}
  {{outlet nodes}}
{{/view}}
```

Say we have a template like above. Route renders into outlet `nodes`. Route wants to re-render `nodes`. Can view detect the change and do something about it?

Comment: How are you re-rendering?

Comment: I'm re-rendering from route via `Route#renderTemplate`

Comment: Isn't didInsertElement not called, when rendered?

Comment: @MartinElvar No it's not. didInsertElement get called when the view itself gets inserted and not anything underneath it.

Comment: I don't want to resort to DOM mutation event if I don't have to. There should be an Ember way of doing this right?

Comment: I decided to refactor the view into template that's being rendered into. This way didInsertElement get to trigger every time.